# Jquery check if function has no arguments execute it without curly brackets

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, parameters, arguments

I'm developing a **jQuery** plugin and using this way to bulid it.

First this is my function of my plugin :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function(data) {
        var width = data.width || 'auto',
    };
}(jQuery));
```

and i'm calling the function to run for example :

```
$('element').myplugin({width: '100px'});
```

it works pretty good but if i called the function without arguments & the curly brackets, the function doesn't work and give an error in the browser console :

```
// Using this way
$('element').myplugin();

// Browser Console
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

So how can i use the both ways with & without arguments (**curly brackets**) like most plugins work?

will appreciate any help alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether `data` has a value before accessing its properties like

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function(data) {
        var width = (data && data.width) || 'auto',
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Another practice I've used in some places is to assign a empty object as the value of `data` is no value is passed like

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function (data) {
        data = data || {};
        var width = data.width || 'auto';
        console.log(width)
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Man, you did the right thing! i just thought it will be difficult and complicated, but you made it simple :) thanks in advance! i appreciate your help :)